# How to make a RecyclerView curved?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I want to make a view that looks like a weight scale, like the image below:

[image]

For that I thought of using a horizontal scrolling RecyclerView with view holders representing each value of the scale and that works fine, but I can't figure out how to make it curved or if it's possible. I want it to be curved to look more like a weight scale. Does anyone know how I can manage to do that?

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: I only have a simple recyclerview so far, but I will update my question

Comment: If you're looking for a simple solution, I would try using scaling and applying `Matrix` to the view. The farther from the middle, the smaller Y scale.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say don't go with RecyclerView. It's not intended to be used for such purpose and it might be very time consuming to make it work. I think that the best way is to write a view from scratch. You can draw the scale manually using onDraw(Canvas), simple math and a bunch of drawing operations. The most difficult part would be to add a scroller to get the fling gesture working nicely.